how do i use animations with the geckolib plugin in mcreator
I'm currently working on a mod that adds all the mobvote mobs using MCreator 2024.1 and Forge for Minecraft 1.20.1. I'm new to animations and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use them.
I've tried adding the exact file name in the animations tab of an animated entity both with and without the .animation.json extension, as well as just the name of the animation, but none of these methods seem to work.
I'm creating the animations using Blockbench. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any tutorials or documentation that explain how to do this, and previous attempts to ask for help haven't been successful.
Could anyone provide some guidance on how to use animations in MCreator? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Welcome on StackOverflow. Say "it doesn't work" doesn't help us to fix your issue. Can you focus on one problem and explain it, with logs, [mre] etc?

im using the geckolib plugin and i made the model and animations in blockbench its a animated entity
